# Compounded Return In Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

if I have a table with a "Date" column and "Daily Return" column that specifies a stock's daily performance. How can I write a KQL query that would create Month to Date, year to date, and Total Cumulative returns? The right 3 columns are what I would be trying to replicate. For the sake of my example, MTD and YTD are the same, but in my actual datasets I obviously have several years worth of data with different months.

| Date | Daily Return | MTD Return | YTD Return | Total Cumulative Return |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/25/2021 | 5.00% | 5.00% | 5.00% | 5.00% |
| 12/26/2021 | 2.00% | 7.10% | 7.10% | 7.10% |
| 12/27/2021 | 3.00% | 10.31% | 10.31% | 10.31% |
| 12/28/2021 | 2.00% | 12.52% | 12.52% | 12.52% |
| 12/29/2021 | 1.00% | 13.64% | 13.64% | 13.64% |
| 12/30/2021 | 3.00% | 17.05% | 17.05% | 17.05% |
| 12/31/2021 | 4.00% | 21.74% | 21.74% | 21.74% |
| 1/1/2022 | 2.00% | 2.00% | 2.00% | 24.17% |
| 1/2/2022 | 2.00% | 4.04% | 4.04% | 26.65% |
| 1/3/2022 | 5.00% | 9.24% | 9.24% | 32.99% |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the cumulative daily return for nth day, formula is

```
Cumulative Daily Return of nth day = [(1 + Daily Return 1) * (1 + Daily Return 2) *..........*(1+ Daily Return n)]- 1
```

**Example**: To calculate the Cumulative return of 2nd day, applying the value in the above formula,
[(1+0.05)*(1+0.02)]-1
=[1.05*1.02]-1
=1.071-1
=0.071

Since Kusto doesn't have any window function like `row_cumsum()` for cumulative product, we can sum the log10 values of daily return value using `row_cumsum()` function and then take the exp10 for the resultant value. Below is the code to calculate the total cumulative returns, cumulative returns for each month and same for each year.

**Code:**

```
let dailyReturns = datatable(Date:datetime, DailyReturn:real)
[
    datetime(2021-12-25), 0.05,
    datetime(2021-12-26), 0.02,
    datetime(2021-12-27), 0.03,
    datetime(2021-12-28), 0.02,
    datetime(2021-12-29), 0.01,
    datetime(2021-12-30), 0.03,
    datetime(2021-12-31), 0.04,
    datetime(2022-01-01), 0.02,
    datetime(2022-01-02), 0.02,
    datetime(2022-01-03), 0.05,
];
dailyReturns
| extend Month = getmonth(Date)
| extend Year = getyear(Date)
| order by Date asc 
| extend log_DR= log10(1+DailyReturn)
| extend month_cumsum_log_DR = row_cumsum(log_DR, Month != prev(Month))
| extend MTD_return=exp10(month_cumsum_log_DR)-1
| extend MTD_return = strcat(round(MTD_return * 100,2), "%")
| extend year_cumsum_log_DR = row_cumsum(log_DR, Year != prev(Year))
| extend YTD_return=exp10(year_cumsum_log_DR)-1
| extend YTD_return = strcat(round(YTD_return * 100,2), "%")
| extend total_cumsum_log_DR = row_cumsum(log_DR)
| extend Total_cumulative_return = exp10(total_cumsum_log_DR) - 1
| extend Total_cumulative_return = strcat(round(Total_cumulative_return * 100,2), "%")
| project Date,DailyReturn,MTD_return,YTD_return,Total_cumulative_return
```

**Output:**

| **Date** | **DailyReturn** | **MTD_return** | **YTD_return** | **Total_cumulative_return** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-25T00:00:00Z | 0.05 | 5.0% | 5.0% | 5.0% |
| 2021-12-26T00:00:00Z | 0.02 | 7.1% | 7.1% | 7.1% |
| 2021-12-27T00:00:00Z | 0.03 | 10.31% | 10.31% | 10.31% |
| 2021-12-28T00:00:00Z | 0.02 | 12.52% | 12.52% | 12.52% |
| 2021-12-29T00:00:00Z | 0.01 | 13.64% | 13.64% | 13.64% |
| 2021-12-30T00:00:00Z | 0.03 | 17.05% | 17.05% | 17.05% |
| 2021-12-31T00:00:00Z | 0.04 | 21.74% | 21.74% | 21.74% |
| 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z | 0.02 | 2.0% | 2.0% | 24.17% |
| 2022-01-02T00:00:00Z | 0.02 | 4.04% | 4.04% | 26.65% |
| 2022-01-03T00:00:00Z | 0.05 | 9.24% | 9.24% | 32.99% |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/ContosoSales?query=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)